# How do I include a margin / gap between my columns and footer in my CSS layout?

Tags: html, css

Cant seem to get a margin or gap between my columns and the footer. I have tried using padding and margin but that doesn't seem to work (see #footer). The end goal is to add a couple of `<div>`'s below the columns. The footer is the first one.I am new to CSS so trying to learn the basics.

Link JSFiddle HTML/CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/41Lpcq2o/

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #F7F7F0;
}

header {
    background-image: url("header.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1000;
    height: 200;
    align-content: center;
    margin-left: 140px;
}

h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 140;
    margin-right: 280;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: white;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#col1 {
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#col2 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #545454;
    background-color: #b6c5a3;
    height: 60;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    color: #492b40;
    font: 11px/12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
```

```
<header>

    <div id="heading">

        <h1> Hello there !!! </h1>

    </div>

</header>



<div id="nav">


    <ul>

        <li> Home </li>
        <li> About </li>
        <li> Contact </li>
        <li> Links</li>

    </ul>

</div>




<div id="Content">

    <div id="col1">

        col1

    </div>

    <div id="col2">

        col2

    </div>

    <div id="col3">

        col 3

    </div>




</div>


<div id="footer">


    <p>Copyright 2004 xyz Association</p>
    <p>All rights reserved etc etc...</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That’s because your `#Content` does not encompass the floated columns, and as such has an effective height of 0.

One easy way to work around this is to make it `display:inline-block` (that will cause it to encompass the floated children), and then give it `width:100%` to make it take the full with as before, when it was displayed as `block`.

```
#Content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/41Lpcq2o/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your `#content` div contains floating elements `#col1`, `#col2` and `#col3`. so you first need to clear the float of `#content` div as follows. check working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41Lpcq2o/7/)

```
#Content:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear the floating don't use the footer, I've added some style for #content check below

```
#Content::after {
    clear:both;
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#footer {
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #545454;
    background-color: #b6c5a3;
    height: 60;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    color: #492b40;
    font: 11px/12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

and removed the clear:both from the footer, check the full example after edit : http://jsfiddle.net/Med7at/cvqpd6je/

Comment: This piece of code appears to add the space :content:' '; Along with the :after. Could you elaborate on what this is doing : content: ' '?